# How can I delete an item from list without re-rendering undeleted Items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, rerender, react-usememo

Thank you for all your comments and helpful remarks.
following your advices, please find below a code sandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-butterfly-uk0fjq?file=/src/item.js

which may help you figure out the issue.
Everything is obvious in the `console`, with multiple logs, which, given the current scale of the example, does not pose any performance issue, but which could if there were a long list of items.

So the question is, how to proceed for preventing items which are not deleted from re-rendering, in spite of the fact that the parent (`ItemList`) re-renders.

The `console` shows the `Item` rendering.

As stated previously, I have used a `useMemo` + `useCallback` combination, but the result proved to be unstable.

Hope this example will help and be more explicit.

**EDIT**

regarding the `console` `log`, strangely, the sandbox example logs 2 times `App`, 2 times `ItemList` and 12 times `Item`, whereas on the computer it logs only 1-1-6 times

Comment: That's just how React works. State informs how the component is rendered. If you change the state, the component will be rendered based off that new state. What precisely is the performance issue?

Comment: But, also: there's a lot of code there that you don't need. 1) Does every item need to be a table? You shouldn't use a `div` in a `th`. 3) `ItemList` should just `map` over the data and return an array of `Items` - no need for a `useEffect`. Those are the one's I caught just briefly looking over the code. Oh, `ItemList` [doesn't need its own state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: can you simplify your example to the core ?

Comment: Please add a sandbox link to the code. And also @Andy is correct. If, maybe you are trying to explain something else, adding a sandbox link will help us understand the question better.

Comment: First of all, read https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html to understand why you should not use the `index` of the array as a key for the elements. Then you should not worry about re-rendering unless it is really affecting your performance (*also read https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-slow-render-before-you-fix-the-re-render*).

Comment: Thank you @GabrielePetrioli, I've modified this issue in the sandbox example.

Comment: @Yash, yes, sure, I've the edited the post and added the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, if you want to minimize the re-renders of the items, you need to make sure of a few things

#### Memoize the component

You can use [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) on the component you want, which will prevent re-renders when the props/state do not change.

so, use

```
export default React.memo(Item);
```

instead of

```
export default Item;
```

#### Make sure the props are the same

When you render the `Item` component you pass `deleteItem` as a prop with a value that is received from the `App` component. However, this function is not a stable (it is redefined each time the App component renders. And since the `App` holds the `items` state, it will rerender after each deletion. This will trigger a new `deleteItem` to be defined, and that will cause the `Item` to re-render.

To make this stable, you need two things.

1. to use [`React.useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) which re-uses the same function when its dependencies remain the same.
2. use the [`function` form](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of the `setItems`

so, instead of

```
const deleteItem = (newItem) => {
  const newItemList = items.filter(
    (item) => item.reference !== newItem.reference
  );
  setItems(newItemList);
};
```

use

```
const deleteItem = React.useCallback((itemToDelete) => {
  setItems((currentItems) =>
    currentItems.filter((item) => item.reference !== itemToDelete.reference)
  );
}, []);
```

---

You also have an issue in your code, where you `.map` the data but then before returning each `Item` you push it in an array and return that instead. Just return the `<Item ..>`

So instead of

```
    {props.data.map((item, index) => {
      const newList = [];
      newList.push(
        <Item
          deleteItem={props.deleteItem}
          key={item.reference}
          item={item}
        ></Item>
      );
      return newList;
    })}
```

do

```
    {props.data.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <Item
          deleteItem={props.deleteItem}
          key={item.reference}
          item={item}
        ></Item>
      );
    })}
```

Updated codesandbox with all changes: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-water-9iyobx

Comment: Thank you so much @Gabriele, I've tested it and it works perfectly, thank you for your clear explanations ! I have modified my old versions in which I was using Memo and useCallback and modified this map function issue, that was in fact the core of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It *sounds* like you want to iterate over your array of objects to produce rows of data in a table with the last cell in each row to be a "remove" button that removes the row. And you can do that. No need for `useEffect`.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Pass in the data
function Example({ data }) {

  // Set the state with the data
  const [ tableData, setTableData ] = useState(data);

  // When a remove button is clicked `filter`
  // out those rows that don't match the row id
  // and reset the state
  function handleRemove(e) {
    const { id } = e.target.closest('tr').dataset;
    const filtered = tableData.filter(obj => {
      return obj.name !== id;
    });
    setTableData(filtered);
  }

  // Create some rows by mapping over the
  // table data
  return (
    <table>
      {tableData.map(row => {
        return (
          <Row
            key={row.name}
            row={row}
            handleRemove={handleRemove}
          />
        );
      })}
    </table>
  );

}

// Create a table row and populate the cells
// with the information from the row object
function Row({ row, handleRemove }) {
  return (
    <tr data-id={row.name}>
      <td>{row.name}</td>
      <td>{row.reference}</td>
      <td>{row.description}</td>
      <td>
        <button
          onClick={handleRemove}
        >Remove
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}

const data = [
 {name: "NAME 1", reference: "REF 1", description: "LOREM IPSUM"},
 {name: "NAME 2", reference: "REF 2", description: "LOREM IPSUM"},
 {name: "NAME 3", reference: "REF 3", description: "LOREM IPSUM"},
 {name: "NAME 4", reference: "REF 4", description: "LOREM IPSUM"},
 {name: "NAME 5", reference: "REF 5", description: "LOREM IPSUM"}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #565656; }
td { border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; padding: 0.5em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Andy for your example, I've tried it and indeed your code is much easier. nevertheless I've inserted various console logs to track the re-rendering, and each Item logs each time the REMOVE button is pressed. In fact that was the issue, which, I admit, was not clear at first sight

Answer (score -1):

When updating the state you need to spread the previous state first before you update it
Example:

```
const deleteItem = (newItem) => {
  const newItemList = items.filter(item => item.reference !== newItem.reference);
  setItems(prev => (...prev, newItemList));
}
```

Comment: it is a delete action. nothing to spread, the `filter` is just fine. Could use a better name for the argument though as `newItem` is misleading.

Answer (score -1):

when updating the state you need to spread the previous state first before you update it

and depends of your type you must return array or object
spreat operator opened previous array or object and then you was add new data
setItems(prev => [...prev, newItemList])

Comment: it is a delete action. nothing to spread, the `filter` is just fine. Could use a better name for the argument though as `newItem` is misleading.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).